# execute ssh-add with ansible raise an error

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ansible, ssh-agent

I am trying to use Ansible to create an infrastructure for ssh connections.

```
- name: Copy ssh key to each server
  copy: src=static_folder_key dest=/home/ec2-user/.ssh/ mode=0600

- name: Enable ssh Agent
  shell: eval $(ssh-agent -s)

- name: Adding ssh key for static forlder project
  shell: ssh-add /home/ec2-user/.ssh/static_folder_key
  sudo: True
```

I create a new ssh key and copy to my servers. Then I execute the agent and later I add the new key to allow the connection. But When I execute the ansible I got this error.

```
TASK: [git | Adding ssh key for static forlder project] *********************** 
failed: [admin_vehicles] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "ssh-add /home/ec2-user/.ssh/static_folder_key", "delta": "0:00:00.004346", "end": "2015-08-12 15:05:00.878208", "rc": 2, "start": "2015-08-12 15:05:00.873862", "warnings": []}
stderr: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
failed: [leads_messages] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "ssh-add /home/ec2-user/.ssh/static_folder_key", "delta": "0:00:00.004508", "end": "2015-08-12 15:05:01.286031", "rc": 2, "start": "2015-08-12 15:05:01.281523", "warnings": []}
stderr: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

If I execute this actions manually, everything goes fine.

```
ssh-add /home/ec2-user/.ssh/static_folder_key 
Identity added: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/static_folder_key (/home/ec2-user/.ssh/static_folder_key)
```

So any tips? Maybe I am missing something in my playbook task?

Comment: Have you tried the authorized_key module?[authorized_key](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html#authorized-key-adds-or-removes-an-ssh-authorized-key)

Answer (score 7):

The solution for this is to invoke `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` before the `ssh-add`. Initially I tried with two Ansible tasks but it failed the same way since they are atomic and cannot persist the state. The ultimate solution I end up with is to invoke both commands in a single task like this:

```
  - name: Evaluating the authentication agent & adding the key...
    shell: |
      eval "$(ssh-agent)"
      ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_svn_ssh
```

Comment: This is (imo) the better answer since it fixes the issue within Ansible. If you have several people that will be using the Playbook, it would be a hassle to have them all configure the ForwardAgent as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 5):

The environment for each task is independent, so you cannot leave `ssh-agent` settings made in one task to others.

I strongly recommend you to utilize SSH agent forwading.  Put the following in `~/.ssh/config`, then run `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add static_folder_key` locally before running `ansible-playbook`.  That's all.

```
Host *
ForwardAgent yes
```

Even when agent forwarding is not an option, you don't have to run `ssh-agent` for a private key file with no passphrase.  Copy the following configuration in `~/.ssh/config` on remote hosts and run `ssh` to  `static-folder-host`.

```
Host static-folder-host
Hostname static-folder-host.static-folder-domain
User static-folder-user
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/static_folder_key
```